# Filtering using ObjectQuery<T> error

Tags: c#, syntax, error-handling, syntax-error

I am creating a accounting / product management program, and  I have problem with code, that should filter my database content inside Data grid view:

```
private void List(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ObjectQuery<TblProduct> filteredProducts = new ObjectQuery<TblProduct>(
            "SELECT VALUE P FROM TblProduct AS P WHERE P.ProductType = " + comboBox1.SelectedValue, salon);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = filteredProducts;
    }
```

and I am using almost same code once more, it is supousted to do almost same thing - filter ad sort my products and create buttons for each product:

```
 private void AddProductsToTabbedPanel()
    {
        foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl1.TabPages)
        {
            ObjectQuery<TblProduct> filProd = new ObjectQuery<TblProduct>("SELECTED VALUE P FROM TblProduct AS P", salon);

            foreach (TblProduct tprod in filProd)
            {
                Button b = new Button();
                b.Text = tprod.Description;
                tp.Controls.Add(b);

            }
        }
    }
```

In both cases i got an error, telling me that EtitySqlException was uhadled, and that there is some bad syntax.

I have taken these codes from one [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL70BEFACCE6BFAF6F) so i dont understand why is it not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the second example you got

```
ObjectQuery<TblProduct> filProd = new ObjectQuery<TblProduct>("SELECTED VALUE P FROM TblProduct AS P", salon);
```

and SELECTED is wrong. should be SELECT

the first one seems ok. Try to change and check if it runs

Also in the tutorial the table inside the query is "TblProducts" not "TblProduct".

Comment: I'll try that SELECT thing, thanks! (Well, my database is named TblProduct, not TblProducts, so thats OK...)

Comment: Still same problem... That error looks like this: 

TblProduct can not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make sure that all referenced variables are in the field, if required schemas are loaded, and if properly refers to namespaces. Middle simple identifier, row 1, column 21

Comment: Have a go with TblProducts, with the "s". Also in his tutorial DB is TblProduct, but in the query he put TblProducts.
Do that and let me know. If it doesn't work I'll try to replicate the test.

Comment: As I said, my Tbl is named Product, not Products... But! I have solved this problem. I have simply created whole project again, exactly same way, and run it through some code comparison program. There is no difference between those codes, and the new one works! I really dont understand it...